# How to search for a element in Cstr array

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a asp page with the below code. I should check if docid is a part of DocId. I tried with a for loop, but its not working. I am new to asp.

```
DocId = DocumentObj.ID 
  if Len(strDisplay) > 0 then
  strDisplay = strdisplay + "&DocID=" + Cstr(DocId)

<script language="JavaScript">

 function ShowDocument(docid) {
    ......
    ....
    }
```

For loop that I used inside ShowDocument()

```
for(i=0; i< Len(Cstr(DocId)); i++){
    if(docid = (Cstr(DocId)(i))){
}
 }
```

Comment: `CStr()` is a VBScript String function used to convert values to strings, it does not behave like an array and it doesn't exist in JavaScript in fact I can't make head nor tail of your code, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in VBScript(Classic ASP):

```
 DocId = DocumentObj.ID 
  if InStr(1,strDisplay,Cstr(DocId)) = 0 then
    strDisplay = strdisplay + "&DocID=" + Cstr(DocId)
```

source to look at http://www.virtualsplat.com/tips/asp-function-instr.asp and if you want to use Javascript then you should use

```
  var n = strDisplay.LastindexOf(DocId);
```

To make your JavaScript IE independent use LastIndexOf instead of .indexof which lately started gives some headaches, and again if n > 0 then do what ever because your DOCID is part of a string. Good source for JavaScript syntax is http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: Do you even know what the OP is asking? Personally I can't see how you can answer this without making assumptions as the OP hasn't been clear enough with his question. Does the DocID contain multiple values if so is it structured like a delimited list or is it something else? The code makes no sense so how are you able to provide a solution?

Comment: @Lankymart: OP question is clear enough for me and if for you it is not - ask him not me. I can consult you on my answer, not his question.